# how to merge multiple parquet files to single parquet file using linux or hdfs command?

Tags: hdfs, parquet

I have multiple small `parquet` files generated as output of hive ql job, i would like to merge the output files to single parquet file?

what is the best way to do it using some `hdfs or linux commands`?

we used to merge the text files using `cat` command, but will this work for parquet as well?
Can we do it using `HiveQL` itself when writing output files like how we do it using `repartition` or `coalesc` method in `spark`?

Comment: Using "parquet-tools merge" is not recommended. Parquet cuts its file into row_groups that correspond to HDFS blocks. "Parquet-tools merge" only places row_groups after row_groups without merging them. Finally, you get the same problem. You can find more explication in [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1115). You also have more explication about "row_groups" for parquet in this [blog](http://ingest.tips/2015/01/31/parquet-row-group-size/).

Comment: Following the ticket mentioned by @Nastasia, this issue will not be solved (at least for now). Anyhow, the solution provided by the merge-tools is now to emit a warning (https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/pull/433).

Answer (score 18):

According to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-460
Now you can download the source code and compile parquet-tools which is built in merge command.

```
java -jar ./target/parquet-tools-1.8.2-SNAPSHOT.jar merge /input_directory/
        /output_idr/file_name
```

Or using a tool like https://github.com/stripe/herringbone

Comment: Anywhere I can just download a jar? Building this is a pain.

Comment: Can this be used for files on AWS S3?

Comment: If you are unifying the files for performance reason you should be aware of parquet-tools merge command limitations: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1115

Comment: If you don't want to build `parquet-tools`, there's a docker container with it at https://hub.docker.com/r/nathanhowell/parquet-tools

Comment: @samthebest yes click the JAR link here. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.parquet/parquet-tools/1.11.1

Answer (score 10):

Using [duckdb](https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet) :

```py
import duckdb

duckdb.execute("""
COPY (SELECT * FROM '*.parquet') TO 'merge.parquet' (FORMAT 'parquet');
""")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it using `HiveQL` itself, if your execution engine is `mapreduce`.

You can set a flag for your query, which causes hive to merge small files at the end of your job:

```
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
```

or

```
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
```

if your job is a map-only job.

This will cause the hive job to automatically merge many small parquet files into fewer big files. You can control the number of output files with by adjusting `hive.merge.size.per.task` setting. If you want to have just one file, make sure you set it to a value which is always larger than the size of your output. Also, make sure to adjust `hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize` accordingly. Set it to a very low value if you want to make sure that hive always merges files. You can read more about this settings in hive [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Give [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) a try, available via PyPi: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*joinem* provides a CLI for fast, flexbile concatenation of tabular data using [polars](https://pola.rs).
I/O is *lazily streamed* in order to give good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.

### Example Usage

Pass input files via stdin and output file as an argument.

```bash
ls -1 path/to/*.parquet | python3 -m joinem out.parquet
```

You can add the `--progress` flag to get a progress bar.

### No-install Containerized Interface

If you are working in a HPC environment, *joinem* can also be conveniently used via [singularity/apptainer](https://apptainer.org).

```bash
ls -1 *.pqt | singularity run docker://ghcr.io/mmore500/joinem out.pqt
```

### Further Information

*joinem* is also compatible with CSV, JSON, and feather file types.
See the project's [README](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem/) for more usage examples and a full command-line interface API listing.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.